# How can i limit the number of characters entered in textbox for div elements in html

Tags: html

Below is my html code where user can see a drop down and on selecting the drop down we will get check box with textbox beside the checkbox.Now i need to limit the no of characters in textbox how can i do this

```
<tr>
        <td align="left" style="padding-left: 50px;" class="space">
            User names :
        </td>
        <td align="left" class="space">
            <div id="dropdownnames" class="dropdowncls" style="width:450px;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

checkbox and textbox

```
 if ($("#dropdownnames").val() != null && $("#dropdownnames").val() != "")
                AccordianFields += AccordianFields == "" ? $("#dropdownnames").val() : "," + $("#dropdownnames").val();

            $("#dropdownnameschk").find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
                AccordianText = AccordianText + $(this).next("#dropdownnameschk").next("#dropdownnamestxt").val() + "~|~";
            });
```

Comment: How the user will see the checkbox and textbox n clicking the dropdown? What plugin are you using? Please post your generated HTML then?

Answer (score 3):

Inputs have an attribute `maxlength` but:
HTML is client side and user controlled so you have to validate on the server side anyway.
Despite this fact the number of characters can be easily limited with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("my-textarea").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (this.value.length > maxLength) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, maxLength);
  }
});
```

Comment: but i need to limit only till 25 characters that too it should be done in html or client side only

Comment: It does not matter to how much characters you want to limit. Just replace `maxLength`. In general, I can easily open my dev tools and remove the maxlength attribute from the textarea and then submit the form.
Thats why you should ALWAYS validate on the server side. Client-Side validation is just for usability.